# Style triggers to set focus on tekstbox not working as expected

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I want to set keyboard-focus on a TextBox  by IsMouseOver trigger of the parent StackPanel.
The TextBox is getting focus and the caret is visible, but as soon as I move the mouse away from the from the StackPanel the TextBox looses focus.

```
 <Style x:Key="TextboxStyle"  TargetType="TextBox">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black" />                  
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="26" />
        <Setter Property="TextAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FF2952CD"/>
        <Setter Property="CaretBrush" Value="Black"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF0D274A"/>            
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsMouseOver, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type StackPanel}}}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="FocusManager.FocusedElement" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" />
                <Setter Property="FocusManager.IsFocusScope" Value="True" /> 
            </DataTrigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Goldenrod"/>
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>                    
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF0D274A"/>
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

I tried many variants but can't get it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. I added an extra

`<Setter Property="FocusManager.FocusedElement" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>`
 in
 `<Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True">`.
Now it is working.